# Did Ezekiel fulfill the 430 days of lying on his left & right side?

Tags: ezekiel

Ezekiel 1:1-2 (KJV)

> 1 Now it came to pass in the thirtieth year, in the fourth month, in the fifth day of the month, as I was among the captives by the river of Chebar, that the heavens were opened, and I saw visions of God.   2 In the fifth day of the month, which was the fifth year of king Jehoiachin's captivity,

Ezekiel 4:5-6 (KJV)

> 5 For I have laid upon thee the years of their iniquity, according to the number of the days, three hundred and ninety days:  so shalt thou bear the iniquity of the house of Israel.   6 And when thou hast accomplished them, lie again on thy right side, and thou shalt bear the iniquity of the house of Judah forty days:

Ezekiel 8:1 (KJV)

> 1 And it came to pass in the sixth year, in the sixth month, in the fifth day of the month, as I sat in mine house, and the elders of Judah sat before me, that the hand of the Lord GOD fell there upon me

It seems Ezekiel began his ordeal of lying on his right & left side seven days after the fifth day of the fourth month of the fifth year & ended on the fifth day of the sixth month of the sixth year.

In the sixth year he is found ***sitting*** before the elders of Judah. He could not have completed the 430 days.

Comment: Honestly i can't imagine a human being doing this for 430 days, the ordeal is way too big for any human being to handle. This is to me another convincing reason to believe that Ezekiel did not finish it (or maybe even start).

Comment: It stands to reason, even without explicit mention, that no human, including Ezekiel, uses the bathroom (so to speak) while lying on one side. As such, the proposed interpretation for the given passage seems forced, to say the least.

Comment: @Bach Dont be so sure...you clearly havent ever heard of this... https://www.themarysue.com/man-keeps-arm-raised-38-years/ i saw it on a major tv network a current affairs news story a while back...there are a whole tribe of these men who do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The solar year is about eleven days longer than twelve lunar months. The Bible does not directly mention the addition of "embolismic" or intercalary months. However, without the insertion of embolismic months, Jewish festivals would gradually shift outside of the seasons required by the Torah. This has been ruled as implying a requirement for the insertion of embolismic months to reconcile the lunar cycles to the seasons, which are integral to solar yearly cycles.
>   -- [Wikipedia - Hebrew Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Leap_months)

Given this, from the fifth day of the fourth month of the fifth year of king Jehoiachin's captivity, to fifth day of the sixth month of the sixth year of Jehoiachin's captivity, there was (approximately, using minimum values):

```
353 days (regular year, 353/354/355 days) +  
 58 days (2 extra months) +  
 29 days (intercalary month)  
--------  
440 days
--------
```

Is it known that there was an intercalary month at the end of the fifth year? For the numbers to work, there must have been.

Answer (score 6):

In Ezekiel Chapter 4 Ezekiel is told to lay on his left side for 390 days and then on his right side for 40 days while prophesying against Jerusalem (facing toward the drawing he made of Jerusalem's siege).  However, to believe he was lying down 24/7 would be erroneous.  If you continue reading in chapter 4 you will find that he was to also make bread (now called Ezekiel bread) and cook it over dung...and eat it while drinking a minimal amount of water.  In fact, the bible doesn't say how many hours a day Ezekiel was to lie on his side.  Thus, finding him sitting in his house with the elders does not void his completion of God's command to lie on his side every day and prophecy toward Jerusalem.

Answer (score 3):

If it is admitted that not all chapters in Ezekiel were written in strict chronological order (e.g. Ezekiel 20:1, more appropriately 29:1-2/26:1-2, 33:21-22/32:1-2), then it remains to be proven that the events of chapter four occurred at the same time as that of chapter one, that is, during the fifth year of the captivity of Jehoiachin. Furthermore, if the 390 days that he was to lay upon his left side is equated at a rate of one day for a year with the time that Israel had then been divided into its kingdoms (4:5), then the approximate year he would have received the pre-exilic visualization (4:1) would have been during the seventh year of the captivity of Jehoiachin. That is two years after the year mentioned in chapter one. Therefore the activities of chapter eight would have already occurred as they concerned the sixth year. Then you would rather be looking at comparing his fasting with the events of chapter twenty (20:1).

This table shows the years as listed in Kings.

```
|  1 Kings 14:21; 31             |  17
|  1 Kings 15:2; 8               |   3
|  1 Kings 15:10; 24             |  41
|  1 Kings 22:42; 50,2 Kings 3:1 |  18
|  2 Kings 8:25; 26              |  12
|  2 Kings 11:3                  |   6
|  2 Kings 13:10                 |  36
|  2 Kings 14:1-2; 23            |16-1
|  2 Kings 14:23,15:1            |  26
|  2 Kings 15:2; 5; 27           |  51
|  2 Kings 15:27,16:1            |  16
|  2 Kings 15:27,16:1,17:1       |  11
|  2 Kings 17:1,18:9             |   7
|  2 Kings 18:2,20:21            |29-4
|  2 Kings 21:1; 21:18           |  55
|  2 Kings 21:19; 26             |   2
|  2 Kings 22:1; 23:30           |  31
|  2 Kings 23:31                 |   0.25
|  2 Kings 23:36; 24:6           |  11
|  2 Kings 24:8                  |   0.25
| Years of Jehoiachin's captivity|   7
| Total                          | 390
```

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! This answer shows promise. I tried to break up the sentences for easier reading and hope I didn't change any meanings. Please take the site [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how the stack exchange works.

Comment: My proof: 1Ki 14:21;31(17) + 1Ki 15:2;8(3) + 1Ki 15:10;24(41) + 1Ki 22:42;50,2Ki 3:1(18) +
2Ki 8:25;26(12) + 2Ki 11:3(6) + 2Ki 13:10(36) + 2Ki 14:1-2;23(16-1) + 2Ki 14:23,15:1(26) + 
2Ki 15:2;5;27(51) + 2Ki 15:27,16:1(16) + 2Ki 15:27,16:1,17:1(11) + 2Ki 17:1,18:9(7) + 2Ki 18:2,20:21(29-4) + 
2Ki 21:1;21:18(55) + 2Ki 21:19;26(2) + 2Ki 22:1;23:30(31) + 2Ki 23:31(.25) + 2Ki 23:36;24:6(11) +
2Ki 24:8(.25) + 7 = 390 years

Comment: I've edited the references into the answer.

Comment: @FrankLuke There ought to be a badge for that....

Answer (score 2):

From the Bible Knowledge Commentary:

> This is the most difficult sign in the book to interpret, partly because of the ambiguity of the text and partly because of a textual problem.
>   God told Ezekiel to lie on his left side and put the sin of the house of Israel on himself. If Ezekiel prostrated himself with his head toward Jerusalem (cf. Dan 6:10), he was facing north when he lay on his left side (and south when he lay on his right side, Eze 4:6). His facing north, which represented Israel, the Northern Kingdom, was to be for 390 days. Ezekiel did not remain in this position 24 hours a day, because the very next sign (Eze 4:9-17) includes some other actions Ezekiel was to do in that time. He probably remained in this position for a portion of each day.
>   After remaining on his left side for 390 days, he was to lie on his right side, and bear the sin of the house of Judah. His facing toward the south, representing Judah, the Southern Kingdom, was to last for 40 days. To symbolize the confinement of the siege, God had Ezekiel tied up with ropes (Eze 4:8). Apparently Ezekiel was tied up only during the time each day when he lay on his side.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing it for nearly four years. I've only been able to lie on one side and I'm not paralyzed. I can walk and sit, but not without pain. And due to an affliction that came out-of-the-blue, and it's rare for anyone to have heard of it, when I lie down it's on one side only. It's interesting to read of people who think they can figure out exactly what Ezekiel's "laying on one side" meant when you're looking through a glass darkly.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and the Help which will assist you in understanding the purpose of the site and how it operates. I don't wish to intrude in any personal way but I would be interested to know (only in the context of Ezekiel's experience) whether your affliction has been diagnosed and if so what is the name of the syndrome or disease ?

Answer (score -1):

The 430 days appears to be a contraction of the 430 years of Jewish internment in Egypt. What is odd about the 430 day count is that if you go from a 5/14 Israel birthday 430 days forward then it lands on 7/17. This is the Apple Computers default date. My research points to 7/17 as the prescribed date when the antichrist will enter the Temple and proclaim himself as a god. Book of Daniel durations all align around the 7/17 date.

Day inclusive is a midpoint 1260 day interval from barack obama being 666 months old on 2/4/2017. The 2/4/2017 date is exactly 1 year after the UN's declared year of light that ended 2/4/2016 at the chichen itza pyramid which is a sun worship device with 365 steps for a solar day. obama is exactly 666 months old one year later. Pope Francis uses this same day 2/4 in 2019 to sign a pact withe the grand imam. He is exactly 30000 days old that day. If you go from 2/4/2017 exactly 33 weeks later then it lands on the virgin birth celestial event 9/23/2017.

No matter which way you go, 2/4 makes the obama 8/4 birthday a centerpoint. On the luciferic, gregorian calendar 8/4 in a non leap year is the 216th day which is a babylonian sexigesimal system source code of 6x6x6.

The masons start time at 4000 years BC and call their count anno lucis or "year of light". To the birth of the last chapter of the mystery babylon, the US, is 5776 years. The false Jewish calendar 2015 - 2016 (UN year of light) is 5776 as well.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below). If I understand you correctly something significant (you indicate) happened on July 2017. Could you just tell me what exactly happened - that is to say what would I have noticed happening on that occasion, myself ?

Comment: We are told in the Prayer of Moses to count days for wisdom. My extensive research points to barack obama as the antichrist.  The UN declared the year of light to be 2015 - 2016. On 04 Feb 2016 the year of light ended at Chichen itza Pyramid in Merida, Mexico. The pyramid is a sun worship device. It has 365 steps for the solar year. Exactly one year later on 04 Feb 2017 obama was exactly 666 months old. 1260 days ( a mid tribulation amount ) = 17 Jul 2020. Any 04 Feb date has the centerpoint of obama's birthday of 04 Aug. In a non leap year 04 Aug is the 216th day of the year or 6x6x6.